# SVG foreignObject childContent fails to render properly in MS Edge

Tags: google-chrome, svg, microsoft-edge

I have a complex SVG with `foreignObject`'s (The header part of this diagram is done as `foreignObject`'s for various reasons). On Chrome 96 everything looks fine. [image: Example]

On MS Edge 96 on first render it looks the same. When I start scrolling down most of the `foreignObject`'s content disappears. Only the very first child of the content remains rendered. The rest does exist in DOM and has all the same properties in the element inspector as the shown element, but it does not render. [image: Example]

This to me seems to be an Edge bug but I cannot find anything close to this on Google or SO. Any ideas how to solve this? Almost seems like Edge exits a render() loop after the first iteration.

Comment: Which version of Edge browser are you using? Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? So that we can have a test and see how to help. With only the image and the text description we can't locate the issue.

Comment: What @YuZhou said.  But in the meantime, try adding `<body></body>` tags around the elements in your `<foreignObject>`. If it doesn't already have them.